# WooCommerce: need hook when admin manually creates order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

One of my sites uses WooCommerce.  The client wants to manually create orders occasionally from within order admin (WooCommerce > Orders > Add Order).  I need to do some additional processing on the order when they click "Save Order" on that page.

Is there a hook available for that?  I've looked through the WooCommerce documentation and list of hooks but found nothing.

Comment: Simply drop all plugin files in a code editor and do a global search for `Add Order` and `add_order`.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta will work for me,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'woocommerce_process_shop_order', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_process_shop_order ( $post_id, $post ) {
        // my code here
}
```

Comment: The name of this hook is a little confusing because it does not include the word "admin" and does include the word "shop". A better name for it would have been: "woocommerce_admin_edit_order_update" or something like that. Because of this confusion I was reluctant to try this hook at first, but I did, and it does indeed activate when the "Save Order" button is pressed.  Thank you Chris for your post.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently found that WooCommerce documentation is basically non-existent in a practical sense. However, have you tried either the `woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end` or `woocommerce_admin_order_actions_start` hooks?

Comment: I really wish those worked. I can't seem to find an action that happens at the END of the order.

Comment: @TheTC I'm assuming you have dug around [Action and Filter Hook Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)? The `woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end` hook does seem to still exist, so maybe you just haven't found the right hook for what you are trying to do.