# Which hooks does WooCommerce used to initiate saving post details and meta details?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am struggling to know how WooCommerce initiate the saving of post and post meta from the dashboard? Please help me with this.

I was able to find the insert code here:

```
includes/class-wc-order.php

public function save() {
      //statement
}
```

Thanks

Comment: May be this thread can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551694/woocommerce-need-hook-when-admin-manually-creates-order

Comment: Hi Zipkund, Thank you so much for your help, but unfortunately I was looking for the initiation of action when we update order post type from the WordPress Admin..

Answer (score 0):

May be this one can be helpful to others..

WooCommerce use post meta to add extra information on default WordPress post. Hence every time we update or create order from WordPress admin, WordPress initiate from this action...

```
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_boxes' ), 1, 2 );
```

> Location: woocommerce/includes/class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php

Everything happens from this hooks.

Note: As this is not related to aboven question but the best hooks to process any action on custom meta box is:

> woocommerce_order_object_updated_props

Thanks